# Using PostgreSQL \COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, jmeter

I'm using JMeter for insert summary data file to PostgreSQL.

I tried `\copy` instead of `COPY` but I'm getting error at `\copy` syntax.

I found out `COPY` is for only server-side,  so I us `\copy`  for client-side.

Here is my query

```
\copy Load(label,success,bytes,latency)
FROM '/Desktop/Summary/oca_sum.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Here is the error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" at position: 1

Comment: `\copy` is a  `psql` meta-command, not a SQL command. So you can **only** use it in `psql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\copy` is not a SQL command but a `psql` command: you need to use `psql`.

Comment: Hi @pifor any other query idea to insert csv file to PostgreSQL table using sql from JMeter

Comment: Sorry but I cannot help with JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

The options are in:

1. Use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-psql.html) command line utility, you will need to install it on the machine where JMeter lives and call it using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)
2. Use [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) class from the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), you can find sample code i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50669444/2897748), in this case you will need to have [Postgres JDBC driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Comment: U mean i need to execute JSR223 Sampler code using OS Process Sampler.

Comment: These are 2 different approaches